# How do I stop a zoom script from expanding the outer sides of a table

Tags: javascript, html, zooming

I just built a website and borrowed a piece of free javascript to zoom in on product images.

The only problem is that the image blows out the sides of my tables and it looks clunky.

Can someone please have a look at this page for example:

http://workplacesafetywarehouse.com/ppe-equipment-list-products/l9265lyymc-12-led-viper-warning-light.htm

Hover over the image and tell me how I can make it zoom in without pushing my table apart?  Note that I don't mind if it pushes the internal 's apart and wraps the text, just the outer perimeter.

I also wouldn't be against replacing it with a better zoom in javascript if that's a better way to go.

Many thanks guys.

Cathy

Answer (score -1):

You should change in this code  `onmouseover="resizeImg(this, 300)"` to `onmouseover="resizeImg(this, 200)"`.  in future you change this value to controle your zoom size. 300 means 3x zoom of your original size image so you mange your zoom size from this.